# How to create ingress on K8S Cluster machine using Terraform?

Tags: kubernetes, terraform, kubernetes-ingress

I am new to K8S and Terraform.  I installed ingress_nginx on K8S Cluster running on Bare-metal.

```
[root@control02 ~]# kubectl get svc -n ingress-nginx
    NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
    docker-hello-world-svc               NodePort    10.xx.xx.121     <none>        8086:30333/TCP               13d
    ingress-nginx-controller             NodePort    10.xx.xx.124     <none>        80:31545/TCP,443:30198/TCP   13d
    ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.xx.xx.85      <none>        443/TCP                      13d
```

I created Deployment, Service and Ingress and am able to access the docker-hello-world-svc from browser successfully.  **Ingress.yaml** is given below

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: hello-world-ing
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
  namespace: ingress-nginx
spec:
  #ingressClassName : nginx
  rules:
  - host: foo.com
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
           name: docker-hello-world-svc
           port:
            number: 8086
```

My requirement is to containerize our PHP based applications on K8S Cluster.

1. Creating ingress via **Terraform's** `resource "kubernetes_ingress" "web"` and `ingress.yaml:kubernetes.io/ingress.class` are same (or)  are they different?
2. How can I create 'ingress' on K8S Cluster machine using Terraform ?

   For example, when I trigger a job from GitLab, Terraform should create a new `"resource kubernetes_ingress"` on K8S Cluster or Control-Plane machine.  Is this possible ?

Kindly clarify on the queries mentioned above and let me know if my understanding is wrong

Answer (score 2):

The `ingress.class` is needed to let the nginx ingress controller understand thathe need to handle this resource.

To create an ingress with terraform you can use the following

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress" "ingress" {
  metadata {
    name      = "ingress-name"
    namespace = "ingress-namespace"
    labels = {
      app = "some-label-app"
    }
    annotations = {
      "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" : "nginx"
    }
  }

  spec {
    rule {
      host = "foo.com"
      http {
        path {
          backend {
            service_name = "svc"
            service_port = "http"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Kindly respond to my question #2

Comment: don't hesitate to clarify the first one, I may did not understood

Answer (score 0):

I was able to create the service on existing K8S Cluster (Bare metal) using the following code

K8S Cluster was setup on `192.168.xxx.xxx` on which I created a service `example`.  We need to mention the `'host'` parameter inside `'kubernetes'` block

```
provider "kubernetes" {
    **host = "https://192.168.xxx.xxx:6443"**
    cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(var.cluster_ca_certificate)}"
    client_certificate = "${base64decode(var.client_certificate)}"
    client_key = "${base64decode(var.client_key)}"
}
  
  resource "kubernetes_service" "example" {
    metadata {
      name = "example"
    }
    spec {
      port {
        port = 8585
        target_port = 80
      }
      type = "ClusterIP"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for,

```
resource "kubernetes_ingress"
```

this,

```
metadata {
   annotations = {
     "kubernetes.io/ingress.class" : "nginx"
   }
}
```

should now be,

```
spec {
  ingress_class_name = "nginx"
}
```

see,

- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#deprecated-annotation
- https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform-provider-kubernetes/commit/647bf733b333bc0ccbabdbd937a6f759800a253a